# N2cms display part of the page only for Admins

Tags: admin, n2cms

I need to show links or may be a form, for just the logged admins.

for example to do something like this :

```
<%if(IsAdmin()){%>
 <div> 
  <a href="" src="BrowseAll"> Show all orders </a>
 <div/>
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following check

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated && HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
```